# Update onedrive file window phone 8.1 - stream Error

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, onedrive

I would like to ask how i can change file content on OneDrive. I'm using OneDrive SDK and when I'm trying change file Name it is working, but with Content I'm getting this error **"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.**

Here is my code - I'm just parsing string to stream...

```
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write("Hello word");
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;



        var updateItem = new Item { Name = txtNazev.Text+".txt", Content = stream };
        var itemWithUpdates = await oneDriveClient
                                        .Drive
                                        .Items[Id]
                                        .Request()
                                        .UpdateAsync(updateItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to access the `Content` property before calling `Request()`, and then use `PutAsync<Item>` instead of `UpdateAsync`.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/a3067b5c52cb077acc6d14efba98f5e8ee396b72/docs/items.md#uploading-contents) for an example (note that it's a little different as it's accessing the item by path, but everything after that will be what you want).